# How to replace text of column in mysql table?

Tags: mysql, replace, sql-update

I have one mysql table with one of the column having some special text. I need to replace this text with new text.

data_table:

```
 Col1 Col2 Col3
  1    tc  That is nice word.
  2    tq  nice question.
```

I need to replace nice word with beautiful in table for Col3. How can i change it?

Regards

Comment: The native function [`REPLACE(column, 'word', 'replacement')`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE MyTable SET Col3 = REPLACE(Col3 ,'nice','beautiful');
```

Comment: above command works but when i replace some html tag Col3 becomes empty.  UPDATE MyTable SET Col3 = REPLACE(Col3 ,'&gt;','>');

Comment: Do you have a any records where Col3 is `&gt;`?  Do you have any sample data you can post?

Comment: ;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;This is first line.&lt;/li&gt;

Comment: ***@Manish***, here is the [***SQL Fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0cb1/1/0) and [***SQL Fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81002f/1/0) that shows that it works.  As you can see, the sub string is being found and replaced.  The confusion may be coming from the fact that you are working with html markup and it may be automatically formatted accordingly.

Comment: My Col3 type is mediumtext. if i use the same command this makes whole table empty.

Comment: ***@Manish***, here is the [***SQL Fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89c23/1/0) and [***SQL Fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12f7b/1/0) that shows it works with ***mediumtext*** as well.  As long as it is a string it should work.

Comment: But in my case whole table become empty. I need to dig out the reason myself.

Answer (score 1):

use mysql REPLACE(col, 'old value','newvalue')

Answer (score 0):

to select =`SELECT REPLACE(col3,'nice','beautiful') from table where col1 = '1'`

to update = `UPDATE table SET Col3 = REPLACE(Col3 ,'nice','beautiful')`

IMHO.. CMIW